# JPA: Adding Child Entity to Parent Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I could need some help since Iam confused by the docs:

I have a Parent JPA Entity:

```
public class Provider implements Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Contact> contacts;
```

And the child:

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Provider provider;
```

And I want JPA to create the relationship if I just add on Contact.

e.g:

```
Contact c = new Contact();
c.provider = providerX;
repo.save(c);
```

What happen now is:

- Contact is inserted into DB (good)
- with the providerX.id in the contact.provider column (good)
- no relationship entry in the provider_contact table appears

I know I could set the contact as a property to provider. `providerX.contacts.add(c); ... repo.save(providerX)`
But this is a bit unhandy and dont feels right.

How can I config the Entities to create this relationship just on saving the contact?

Thanks for any help.
Gregor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to add mappedBy in the non owning entity to establish the bidirectional relation, and initialize the list so you only need to add to it when you need

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="provider")
private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();//im supposing java 8
```

Then since your relation is bidirectional its logical to have each side of the relation mapped to the other, hence you will need to have reference of each side in the other side

```
Contact c = new Contact();
c.setProvider(providerX);
providerX.getContacts().add(c);//please use getters and setters  
repo.save(c);
```

And at the end you need to cascade the provider inside the contacts so that when you persist the contacts, the provider gets persisted

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Provider provider;
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains what the "mappedBy" is for. :)

Comment: Hmm I missed something... I got an `PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: de.sklorz.content.entities.Provider`

Comment: @GregorSklorz if you are cascading entities and you set the id you will have this exception, you need to set your id to null

Comment: Yes. In my case the providerX.id is set and the contact.id is null. Since I want to attach the contact to the provider.

Comment: if you want to attach an already persisted provider you need to retrieve it from database and do the same, providerX = providerRepo.find(provider.getId());

Comment: OK. And then: `contact.setProvider(providerX); repo.save(contact);` ...should work?

Comment: OR it must be: `providerX.getContacts().push(contact); repo.save(providerX);` ??

Comment: the provider you are trying to attach to the contact is already in the database and you have it's id ?

Comment: Yes :) I have the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154463/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-gregor-sklorz).

Comment: What is parent entity?